# how to create jmeter running Vusers graph

Tags: graph, jmeter

Though many have asked the same question and I could not create Running Vusers graph in jmeter       not exactly like LR but like the one which could explain what it is meant to . Is there a way to do so??

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Send a link to what you want the graph to look like.

Comment: here, http://merc.tv/img/scr/lr/runningvusers.jpg which explains how the users come into system with time but with jtl file it seems tricky to generate the same in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

The Plugin **Active Threads over time** which could be downloaded from [http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/]  provided the graph I needed.